# Can I use this distribution to model my data according to these plots?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, fitting, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I used the Anderson-Darling and the KS tests to decide whether my data and the distribution fitted on my data has the same distribution. Both tests rejects the null hypothesis.

However when I look at the histograms, densities and the qqplot, it seems to me that my data and the distribution fitted on it are not completely different.

I have 2000 data points. Can I use this fitted distribution to model my data?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your comment says it all. " it seems to me that my data and the distribution fitted on it are not completely different." Not completely different is a different answer then distributed in the same way. With enough data points any bias can be detected. Let me turn the question around for you: why would your fitted distribution be good enough to justify using it. What are its disadvantages?